# How can I change "Users" related labels in the wordpress dashboard

Tags: users, labels

I am looking to change all the labels related to the `Users` type to `Participants`. Example `Add New Participant`, `Edit Participant`, etc.
Similar to changing the `posts` post type labels to `News` or some other name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [admin_menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_menu/) filter and [global variables](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables) $submenu and $menu to modify the existing menu text, example as follow. (Note, in the list, seems that $submenu did not recorded over there)

The following code is proved to work with assumption that there is

- no plugin interference (admin menu tweaking or related plugins)
- theme haven't touched any related areas
- the following code is placed in theme functions.php

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'q364210_modify_menu_name', 0 );
function q364210_modify_menu_name() {
    global $submenu, $menu;

    // you may var_dump($submenu) or ($menu) here to shows the array information to find out which one is registered in the variable and then add the test like following

    // main menu (top)
    foreach ($menu as $main_menu => $single_menu) {
        foreach( $single_menu as $key => $menu_item ) {
            if( $menu_item === 'Users' ) {
                $menu[$main_menu][$key] = 'Participants';
            }
        }
    }

    // reset tempoary variable for next use avoid conflicts
    unset($menu_item);
    unset($key);

    // the example here use if for testing, you may also use switch clause to test if there are multiple pages, eg 'options-general.php' and so on

    // submenu
    foreach ($submenu as $submenu_file => $submenu_items) {
        if( $submenu_file === 'users.php' ) {
            foreach ($submenu_items as $key => $menu_item) {
                if( $menu_item[0] === 'All Users' ) {
                    $submenu[$submenu_file][$key][0] = 'All Participants';
                }

                if( $menu_item[0] === 'Add New' ) {
                    $submenu[$submenu_file][$key][0] = 'Add New Participant';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or you may also find any admin menu plugins to tweak.

Edited: Further reply about the asker's inquiry about the possibility in further customisation.

The above method is of course, perfectly update the label on the menu.
However, one may want to do a sophisticated customisation to all label inside the related pages.

> Is it possible also to change Users on the wp-admin/users.php page (next to Add New button?

The short answer is No.

The long answer is...

Depends on how much time and how much effort you are willing to. You could use [`add_menu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) and [`add_submenu_page`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/) to add your own menu. Then you could create those files based on the original one but you have to take care of a few files and situations including User list, Add User, Edit User and Profile (when user is not an admin). And you need to test it carefully. (for saving data part while UI display is just a matter of CSS, JS)

It requires quite a lot of works to accomplish the effect. It may be worth to raise up to the Core Term in the future about this feature so they can put some hook over the place to benefit different situations and visual needs.

Comment: That worked! Thanks!!
Is it possible also to change `Users` on the `wp-admin/users.php` page (next to `Add New` button?
Also change `Edit User [Name]` to `Edit Participant [Name]` on the `wp-admin/user-edit.php` page?

Comment: Since the answer is too long, I have updated the answer.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to clarify that. It makes sense. I will look at submitting the request to the Core Team.